# How to remove slugs from multiple custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting, slug

I've seen several posts lately with people easily removing the slugs from **a single** custom post type via the following function:

```
function hf_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if(('pop-tags' == $post->post_type || 'furniture-type' == $post->post_type) && 'publish' == $post->post_status) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link 
);

   return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'hf_remove_slug', 10, 3 );

function hf_parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'pop-tags', 'furniture-type', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hf_parse_request' );
```

However I've been unable to get this to work when I add in multiple custom post types. Can anyone help with this/explain?

Comment: Could just be a typo on WPSE but you're missing a quote mark after `'custom_post_type2`. You might also try reformatting the remove_cpt_slug function as a positive match: `if(('custom_post_type1' == $post->post_type || 'custom_post_type2' == $post->post_type) && 'publish' == $post->post_status)` do your str_replace and return.

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine - a good thought, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working either (neither post types seem to get their slug removed). I also did check my quotes, I just forgot to include on in my initial question - I've update my functions in the question to match what I've tried.

Comment: If you're testing for the opposite case, then you need to reverse what it's doing when it passes that test- you want to replace the link when it passes, not return the link unaltered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have your if doing the opposite of what you want. You're returning the unaltered link if you're on 'furniture-type' or 'pop-tags'.

This should work:

```
function hf_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if(('pop-tags' == $post->post_type || 'furniture-type' == $post->post_type) && 'publish' == $post->post_status) {
        $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link);
        return $post_link;
    }

   return $post_link;
}
```